# firebase database strategy for simultaneous connections of 100k+?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

If you are going to implement a firebase backend service that goes insanely viral and has a growth rate of over 40% per 10 days and you hit the quota of the blaze plan of nothing over 100,000 simultaneous connections. What kind of working strategies could be implemented with firebase for handling simultaneous connections of over 100k? 1M? 100M? 1B!!?

Comment: I think 100000 is really big number to reach but I wonder the solution to this.

Comment: Right! I bet it would be epic! :)

Comment: This is not really an appropriate question for this site is it's regarding networking-related infrastructure administration and is pretty open ended. However, if your app goes that viral, grats to start with and reach out to Firebase support for a custom solution.

Answer (score 4):

100k concurrents is quite a lot of concurrent connections, but not out of the question for large apps, as we've had applications with > 1MM.

In general, the strategy for doing this involves sharding data across multiple databases. This is pretty trivial if the data is all independent (e.g. per user todo list), since you can assign a developer to a database and you never have to sync across databases.

Read only data (such as 1:N chat) is generally also pretty straightforward, as you can perform the same "allow someone to connect to any of N copies of the same database", and have a single user/job update all of them with the same information.

For more complicated schemes (particularly 1:1 chat), allowing developers to connect to any database, then syncing data across databases using Cloud Functions or another system is probably recommended.

If you're expecting to realistically hit 100k+ concurrents, feel free to [reach out to our support team](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) with more info on the use case and we're happy to work with you.